# Android Marshmallow does not detect an SD card formatted as internal when inserting it

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, sd-card, adoptable-storage

I have an el cheapo burner smartphone I bought due to my previous phone getting stolen, running Android 6.0. I formatted an external SD card for use as internal, and proceeded to spend the entire night downloading about 1 GB worth of apps and migrating them to the SD card. Then I rebooted my phone, and ran into a boot loop. To break it I started my phone without the SD card. It started properly, but now it won't detect my SD card when I insert it. Google didn't turn up any meaningful results for my issue. If I tell Android to forget that card, I'm going to have to spend another 4 hours downloading apps.

Is there any way I can get Android to manually try to mount the SD card again?

Comment: If it lost its encryption key (or scrambled it), chances are zero. Apart from that: Your title says "Nougat", but description and tags say "Marshmallow"; which one is it?

Comment: The same thing happened before the boot loop happened and I fixed it by just restarting the phone. I'm not sure if it's a problem with Android or with my phone's hardware, but it seems to only detect my SD card on system boot. And when my phone fails to start with the card inserted, that's where I'm in a pickle.

Comment: I've never used adoptable-storage. But considering it means the card is used as internal-storage, it makes absolutely sense it might have to be mounted during boot (and not after the system is fully up and running). // No further ideas, so someone else has to pick up here.